# how to list items on Amazon using UPC?

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

how to list items on Amazon using UPC?

I am not able to list product on amazon with custom ASIN template with UPC code.

I got following error

SKU XXX, Missing Attributes standard_product_id. SKU XXX does not match any ASIN. Creation of a new ASIN requires the following missing attributes: standard_product_id. Feed ID: 0. For details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/errorcode/200692370